# phonegap application ajax calls fail after upgrading android from 2.3.3 to 4.0.3

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have developed a mobile application using :

- jquery mobile 1.1
- jquery 1.7.2
- cordova/phonegap 2.0.0

this application fires AJAX post calls to a remote server, something like:

```
$.ajax(
type: "post",
cache: false,
timeout: 30000,
url: "http://"+ username+":"+password +"@mycompany.com/mysite/and/so/on.asmx",
contentType: "text/xml",
// other params...
```

The application works fine in Android 2.2 and 2.3.3. So far so good.

The users have upgraded to Android 4.0.3, the main page loads fine, but ajax calls don't work anymore.
Also in the emulator of android 4.1 it's the same.

Considering nothing else has changed but the platform, what could have changed in the Webkit layer to cause the problem?
Are there known migration rules to be followed?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade PhoneGap to its latest version (2.2.0)?

Comment: Can you test in a Android 4.0.3 emulator and try to see what exception/error is causing the ajax to fail? Has anything changed server side or in some other component in between the device and the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a lot of things are more locked down in newer versions of android to improve security. Passwords included in the url are insecure, especially if you don't use https, so some browsers no longer support them.

I haven't seen anything specific to android webview, but it is definitely deprecated in google's other browser.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150

Try setting the credentials in a header instead:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: {},
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa(user + ':' + pass));
        },
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });
```

Comment: hi om, then your answer lead me to a security issue.

Comment: Hi Tom then your asnwer lead me to a security issue. actually I got stuck by the way you suggested because my remote service, that is a sharepoint service, would refuse me this kind of authentication, and then I ended up passing the credentials straight into the URL.
Anyway with this problem dealing with android 4 I need to turn back trying to resolve this issue (sharepoint refuses this kind of authentication).

Comment: Update: passing credentials in the beforeSend callback function solves the issue! 
Tom's hint was right.
Actually it works also on Android 2.3.3 and 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<access origin="your server" subdomains="true" />` to config.xml and you are done. No need to rewrite all ajax calls ;-) Just done it with my application and its working fine on all android versions.